# Working with multiple objects in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

There's a table view that has a list of things. The user can select multiple rows in this table. I'm storing each in an array.

I then want to loop through that array to get each item in it's own string that I can set it up to a key.

Here's something I have tried:

```
for (NSString *str in self.myArray) {
        if ([str isEqual:@"Blah"]) {
            self.blahString = str;
        } else {
            self.blahString = @"";
        }

        if ([str isEqual:@"Blah Blah"]) {
            self.blahblahString = str;
        } else {
            self.blahblahString = @"";
        }

        if ([str isEqual:@"Blah Blah Blah"]) {
            self.blahblahblahString = str;
        } else {
            self.blahblahblahString = @"";
        }
}

if (self.myArray.count == 0) {
     [self.answersToPass setObject:@"" forKey:@"Blah"];
     [self.answersToPass setObject:@"" forKey:@"Blah Blah"];
     [self.answersToPass setObject:@"" forKey:@"Blah Blah Blah"];
} else {
     [self.answersToPass setObject:self.blahString forKey:@"Blah"];
     [self.answersToPass setObject:self.blahblahString forKey:@"Blah Blah"];
     [self.answersToPass setObject:self.blahblahblahString forKey:@"Blah Blah Blah"];
}
```

The goal here is if the user doesn't select anything, then just set each objectForKey to an empty string, else pull out each string and match it to it's right key.

EDIT:

I believe I have solved my issue. I scratched the above code completely.

I found an 'order-of-operation' error on my end. Totally my fault. Should have looked through my code line-by-line more carefully.

If I encounter any issues with this again I'll update the post here.

I appreciate everyone's input and help. I apologize for not being thorough enough in my question.

Comment: when the loop is over, ofcourse the string will contain the last value in the array. If you want to pull out each string, then you need to store the string for evrry iteration. But what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I need to store each string. These relate to answers that need to be sent to a database. Any tips on how to store each time would be helpful. Everything I've tried has not worked.

Comment: can you show what you tried ? u mean , u want to store the string in database for every iteration ?

Comment: if you already have the data in an array - `self.myArray` - then it's already available to use within the app.  If you need to persist each string in a data store, then go have a look at one of the many tutorials on CoreData or Realm

Comment: Teja: I'm sending a lot of data together to my database. I'm sending a NSMutableDictionary. So each of these strings in the array is associated with a key. I need to pull out each string and match it with it's key.

Comment: Any items from the list that's not added to the array I'm sending as just an empty string.

Comment: Post a full example showing your input and what you want to get as output.  Your question makes no sense as it stands now.

Comment: Why are you using the same string as both key and value?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not super lucidly worded, so I'll do my best but I'm not sure what precisely you want.

1) It sounds like you are checking all the time if the user selected something.  Why?  This is a terrible idea.  Instead, [add a responder to change stuff](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/RowSelection/RowSelection.html) when the user actually does select something.

2) This manual setup is not great - what if someday you want to have 500 different items?  Are you going to manually enter each if statement?

Try something more like this.

```
for (NSString *string in self.myArray)
{
    if (self.answersToPass[string])
        [self.answersToPass setObject: string forKey:string];
    for (id key in self.answersToPass)
        if (key isEqualToString:(string))
            [self.answersToPass setObject: string forKey:key];
        else [self.answersToPass setObject: "" forKey:key];
}
```

Please note that the above is not tested so you may have to fix some bug with my obj c notation or something but it should show the right idea.

I would note that this basic structure of a dict with strings equaling each other sounds very silly.  Why store a key and value that either are equal or where the value is null and then check each time?  Wouldn't it be easier to just hold an array of booleans?  Or a map of strings to booleans?

Comment: The code posted above is ran when the user taps a button. I am checking when a cell is selected to check and uncheck it. Some of the keys are a little different than what's listed as the cell title though. As for the last point, I can try to push them to modify that but I'm not coding any of the server side logic.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0x1571bd510> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Comment: You probably have to make a copy, edit the copy and then hangs the original to be the copy. The point is the logic not the code itself. There are my easier ways to check and uncheck cells....

Answer (score 0):

You will better define a data structure (e.g. NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary) as a property, and store the str into it, so that you can access them at a later time.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array; 
for (NSString *str in self.myArray) {
[array addObject str];
}
```